# How to force csh use local bin?

Tags: csh

I'm only able to install new tool in my local directory.

After ./configure --prefix=/local/directory, new tool is installed my local bin.

But by default it's still point to the old version.

How to force csh to use local installed version?

Comment: I've added `setenv PATH ${PATH}:/local/bin`, but if I run which, it's still point to the old version.

Comment: Unfortunately, the proposed duplicate doesn't solve the finer point here of *prepending* the local directory to $PATH

Comment: Don't use `csh`. Use some better shell ([zsh](http://zsh.org/), [fish](http://fishshell.com/), ...). Read absolutely [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell searches the directories in the order that they appear in the PATH environment variable.  If there is another command with the same name in one of the other PATH directories, it will pick it up before getting to the new directory that you appended to the end of the PATH variable.  You would need to *prepend* the new directory to the PATH environment variable.

```
setenv PATH /local/directory/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I've added `setenv PATH /local/directory/bin:$PATH` to the first line of .cshrc. After source ~/.cshrc, run which, but it's still not picking up local/bin. Try add which before and after setenv PATH. First print old bin, second print new bin. But if I run which, still print old bin location.

Comment: Found the reason, there are some scripts in my .cshrc secretly changed PATH.